# Выборка только с определенными связями

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    `players`.*
FROM
    `players`
LEFT JOIN `players_modes` ON `players`.`id` = `players_modes`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `modes` ON `players_modes`.`mode_id` = `modes`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `players_styles` ON `players`.`id` = `players_styles`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `style` ON `players_styles`.`style_id` = `style`.`id`
WHERE
    (`players`.`game_id` = '3') AND(`style`.`id` IN('3', '4', '5'))
```

Данный вариант не подходит потому что будут выбирать все записи в которых есть связи с id 3 или 4 или 5. А нужно выбирать запись только если есть эти связи. 
Пример:
Если указать [1,2,3] и у одной из записей несколько связей(например: 1,2,3), а у другой (1,2,3,5) то in выберет обе записи.

Рабочий вариант которые делает то что нужно:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM players AS p
INNER JOIN players_styles ps ON p.id ps.player_id
WHERE p.game_id = '3' AND ps.style_id IN('3', '4', '5')
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

НО, с INNER JOIN нельзя будет использовать остальные JOIN'ы, а они нужны обязательно. Еще один вариант это делать подзапрос, но это затратно по ресурсам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> с INNER JOIN нельзя будет использовать остальные JOIN'ы

Кто тебе сказал такую глупость?

> нужно выбирать запись только если только эти записи

```
SELECT     `players`.*
FROM       `players`
INNER JOIN `players_styles` ON `players`.`id` = `players_styles`.`player_id`
INNER JOIN `style` ON `players_styles`.`style_id` = `style`.`id`
LEFT  JOIN `players_modes` ON `players`.`id` = `players_modes`.`player_id`
LEFT  JOIN `modes` ON `players_modes`.`mode_id` = `modes`.`id`
WHERE      `players`.`game_id` = '3' 
GROUP BY   `players`.`id`
HAVING     SUM(`style`.`id` NOT IN ('3', '4', '5')) = 0
   AND     COUNT(DISTINCT `style`.`id`) = 3
```

Кстати. Таблицы `players_modes` и `modes` в запросе в принципе никак не используются. И их удаление опять же в принципе не может изменить результата, если не считать времени выполнения запроса.

Comment: Магия) Объяснить можете как это работает?

Comment: @edvardpotter Что именно НЕпонятно?

Comment: Сложно воспринять это, SUM(`style`.`id` IN ('3', '4', '5')) = COUNT(`style`.`id`) тут всегда 6 = 6, если это условие убрать и написать как в первоначальном варианте то результат такой же

Comment: *Сложно воспринять это, `SUM(style.id IN ('3', '4', '5')) = COUNT(style.id)`* Смотри внимательнее, я немного изменил текст запроса. Так он должен стать понятнее.

Comment: Извините за глупость но до сих пор не понятно. Получаем сумму всех значений(почему сумму а не кол-во?) и проверяем чтобы было равно нулю, только зачем вообще эта проверка нужна, и почему не следует делать проверку в WHERE?

Comment: *почему сумму а не кол-во?* Да потому что количество будет равно количеству записей, и пофиг, чем кончилось сравнение. Сравнение было? плюсадын... А сумма работает, потому что при выполнении условия получается True, которое преобразуется в 1, а при невыполнении соответственно False и 0. Т.е. ``SUM(`style`.`id` NOT IN ('3', '4', '5')) = 0`` означает "ни одно из сравнений не дало True". Что эквивалентно "нет ни одного значения, не входящего в этот список".

Comment: Да уже понял это, спасибо за оперативный ответ и разъяснения)